# How to view durability again?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing version 1.14 and it appears that <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> won't show me the durability of my items anymore. I've been playing Minecraft for many years, did they remove the ability to see Durability in 1.14?

Answer (score 3):

It still works for me consistently. Try pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to see the command list, and if it is changed, it should show up there. Otherwise, just make sure your <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> keys work independently, and if nothing's wrong there and the list still says to use <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, then make sure your system isn't treating <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> as a shortcut to something else (not sure why it would unless you made it do that...).

Otherwise, try loading another version and seeing if it works there; if not, either your keyboard is broken, your computer is overriding or not receiving the shortcut, or something else system-related (try checking your cords), and if so, try reinstalling 1.14.